# Html.EditorFor SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

With the introduction of Html.EditorFor everything just seems easier -- All but one thing: EditorFor<SelectList>

What would be the best way to make it work? What I need is either a checkboxlist, a dropdownlist or the like.

I can easily find mvc1 solution for the problem, but mvc2 seems to not be there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the templating available - See ScottGu's post on it http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx